# Memory leak after allocating multidimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, memory-leaks

I wrote a simple program to read any square matrix and compute its determinant. However, according to Valgrind, it appears to be leaking memory.

Example session:

```
./det
4 23 4
2 -5 2
45 2 40
330.000000
```

Here is Valgrind output:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes ./det                                                                                                  ⏎
==5586== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==5586== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==5586== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==5586== Command: ./det
==5586== 
4 23 4
==5586== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5586==    at 0x4C2D1CA: strcat (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5586==    by 0x400EE6: readline (det.c:132)
==5586==    by 0x400B13: parse_into (det.c:53)
==5586==    by 0x40084D: main (det.c:20)
==5586==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==5586==    at 0x4C29F90: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5586==    by 0x4C2C33F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5586==    by 0x400EB4: readline (det.c:127)
==5586==    by 0x400B13: parse_into (det.c:53)
==5586==    by 0x40084D: main (det.c:20)
==5586== 
2 -5 2
==5586== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5586==    at 0x4C2D1CA: strcat (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5586==    by 0x400EE6: readline (det.c:132)
==5586==    by 0x400C66: parse_into (det.c:79)
==5586==    by 0x40084D: main (det.c:20)
==5586==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==5586==    at 0x4C29F90: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5586==    by 0x4C2C33F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5586==    by 0x400EB4: readline (det.c:127)
==5586==    by 0x400C66: parse_into (det.c:79)
==5586==    by 0x40084D: main (det.c:20)
==5586== 
45 2 40
==5586== Invalid read of size 8
==5586==    at 0x400929: determinant (det.c:37)
==5586==    by 0x400864: main (det.c:21)
==5586==  Address 0x51d9040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 64 free'd
==5586==    at 0x4C2C29E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5586==    by 0x400D39: allocate_matrix (det.c:95)
==5586==    by 0x400BFB: parse_into (det.c:72)
==5586==    by 0x40084D: main (det.c:20)
==5586== 
==5586== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5586==    at 0x400945: determinant (det.c:37)
==5586==    by 0x400864: main (det.c:21)
==5586==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==5586==    at 0x4C29F90: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5586==    by 0x4C2C33F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5586==    by 0x400DBD: allocate_matrix (det.c:102)
==5586==    by 0x40083D: main (det.c:19)
==5586== 
==5586== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5586==    at 0x40094F: determinant (det.c:37)
==5586==    by 0x400864: main (det.c:21)
==5586==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==5586==    at 0x4C29F90: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5586==    by 0x4C2C33F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5586==    by 0x400DBD: allocate_matrix (det.c:102)
==5586==    by 0x40083D: main (det.c:19)
==5586== 
0.000000
==5586== Invalid read of size 8
==5586==    at 0x400E24: free_matrix (det.c:113)
==5586==    by 0x40087F: main (det.c:22)
==5586==  Address 0x51d9040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 64 free'd
==5586==    at 0x4C2C29E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5586==    by 0x400D39: allocate_matrix (det.c:95)
==5586==    by 0x400BFB: parse_into (det.c:72)
==5586==    by 0x40084D: main (det.c:20)
==5586== 
==5586== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==5586==    at 0x4C2B200: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5586==    by 0x400E4B: free_matrix (det.c:114)
==5586==    by 0x40087F: main (det.c:22)
==5586==  Address 0x51d9040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 64 free'd
==5586==    at 0x4C2C29E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5586==    by 0x400D39: allocate_matrix (det.c:95)
==5586==    by 0x400BFB: parse_into (det.c:72)
==5586==    by 0x40084D: main (det.c:20)
==5586== 
==5586== 
==5586== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5586==     in use at exit: 624 bytes in 14 blocks
==5586==   total heap usage: 17 allocs, 4 frees, 761 bytes allocated
==5586== 
==5586== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 6
==5586==    at 0x4C29F90: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5586==    by 0x4C2C33F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5586==    by 0x400EB4: readline (det.c:127)
==5586==    by 0x400B13: parse_into (det.c:53)
==5586==    by 0x40084D: main (det.c:20)
==5586== 
==5586== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 6
==5586==    at 0x4C29F90: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5586==    by 0x4C2C33F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5586==    by 0x400EB4: readline (det.c:127)
==5586==    by 0x400C66: parse_into (det.c:79)
==5586==    by 0x40084D: main (det.c:20)
==5586== 
==5586== 64 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 6
==5586==    at 0x4C29F90: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5586==    by 0x400B41: parse_into (det.c:59)
==5586==    by 0x40084D: main (det.c:20)
==5586== 
==5586== 96 (24 direct, 72 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 5 of 6
==5586==    at 0x4C2C29E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5586==    by 0x400D39: allocate_matrix (det.c:95)
==5586==    by 0x400BFB: parse_into (det.c:72)
==5586==    by 0x40084D: main (det.c:20)
==5586== 
==5586== 448 bytes in 7 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 6 of 6
==5586==    at 0x4C29F90: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5586==    by 0x4C2C33F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5586==    by 0x400DBD: allocate_matrix (det.c:102)
==5586==    by 0x40083D: main (det.c:19)
==5586== 
==5586== LEAK SUMMARY:
==5586==    definitely lost: 552 bytes in 11 blocks
==5586==    indirectly lost: 72 bytes in 3 blocks
==5586==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5586==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5586==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5586== 
==5586== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==5586== ERROR SUMMARY: 13 errors from 12 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I don't know why, but during the Valgrind session the result is wrong! How can it output `330` and `0` with the same input? Are the Valgrind errors to be trusted?

Here's the complete code. As you can see, I always call `free()` after using the heap.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MATRIX 8
#define CHUNK 32

double determinant(double **, size_t);
size_t parse_into(double **);
double **allocate_matrix(double **, size_t);
void free_matrix(double **);
char *readline();


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    double **matrix = NULL;
    size_t N;
    matrix = allocate_matrix(matrix, MATRIX);
    N = parse_into(matrix);
    printf("%lf\n", determinant(matrix, N));
    free_matrix(matrix);
    return 0;
}


double determinant(double **matrix, size_t side) {
    if (side == 1) {
        return matrix[0][0];
    } else if (side == 2) {
        return matrix[0][0] * matrix[1][1] - matrix[0][1] * matrix[1][0];
    }

    // Make the matrix triangular
    int i, j, t, r = 1;
    for (j = 0; j < side; j++) {
        if (!matrix[j][j]) return 0;
        for (i = j + 1; i < side; i++) {
            double ratio = matrix[i][j] / matrix[j][j];
            for (t = 0; t < side; t++) {
                matrix[i][t] -= ratio * matrix[j][t];
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < side; i++) {
        r *= matrix[i][i];
    }
    return r;
}


size_t parse_into(double **matrix) {
    char *row = readline();
    size_t t;
    size_t N = 0, M = 0;
    size_t i = 1, j = 0;

    int *first_row;
    if (!(first_row = malloc(MATRIX * sizeof(first_row)))) {
        puts("Could not allocate memory.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    char *number = strtok(row, " ");
    while (number) {
        if (N == MATRIX) {
            first_row = realloc(first_row, 2 * N * sizeof(first_row));
        }
        first_row[N++] = atoi(number);
        number = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    M = N;
    matrix = allocate_matrix(matrix, N);
    for (t = 0; t < N; t++) {
        matrix[0][t] = first_row[t];
    }

    while (--M) {
        j = 0;
        row = readline();
        char *number = strtok(row, " ");
        while (number) {
            matrix[i][j++] = atoi(number);
            number = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
        i++;
    }
    free(row);
    return N;
}


double **allocate_matrix(double **matrix, size_t side) {
    size_t i;

    if (!(matrix = realloc(matrix, sizeof(*matrix) * side))) {
        puts("Could not allocate memory.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < side; i++) {
        matrix[i] = NULL;
        if (!(matrix[i] = realloc(matrix[i], sizeof(matrix[i]) * side))) {
            puts("Could not allocate memory.");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}


void free_matrix(double **matrix) {
    size_t length = sizeof(matrix[0]) / sizeof(matrix[0][0]);
    while (length--) free(matrix[length]);
    free(matrix);
}


char *readline() {
    char *input = NULL;
    char tmpbuf[CHUNK];
    size_t inputlen = 0, tmplen = 0;

    do {
        fgets(tmpbuf, CHUNK, stdin);
        tmplen = strlen(tmpbuf);
        inputlen += tmplen;
        input = realloc(input, inputlen + 1);
        if (!input) {
            puts("Could not allocate memory.");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        strcat(input, tmpbuf);
    } while (tmplen == CHUNK - 1 && tmpbuf[CHUNK - 2] != '\n');

    return input;
}
```

**EDIT** Here is the correct and working code, in case anyone is interested:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/85769/reading-a-matrix-and-computing-the-determinant

Comment: In addition to the posted answers, the statement `matrix[i] = NULL` just before `realloc` call in `allocate_matrix` discards the currently allocated row when you reallocate. You'd need to keep track of the matrix size, then set to null only the _new_ rows if the size increases, and free rows if the size decreases.

Comment: There are other problems with your code. For example think about what would happen if the `realloc` call fails? When assigning it back to the pointer you reallocate you will loose the original pointer.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Why do I have to pay attention to realloc? I thought that if my program cannot allocate memory it might as well crash, since all would be lost anyway.

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile.  there are two warnings raised in the first line of the main() function.  1 warning for each of the unused parameters: argc and argv.   These are not the only problems.   suggest compiling with all warnings enabled and fix the warnings.

Comment: Most people try to handle failures gracefully, professionally it often *required* that no program crash out of the blue. And out of memory might not be the only reason for `realloc` to fail.

Comment: the posted code is exiting on any error without calling free for each allocated memory area.

Comment: this code block:   input = realloc(input, inputlen + 1);
        if (!input) {
            puts("Could not allocate memory.");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } , when realloc fails, will have overlayed the prior  memory pointer in 'input' with 'NULL', resulting in a memory leak.  when using realloc always assign to a temporary pointer, test the temporary pointer, and if temporary pointer not NULL, then assign the temporary pointer to the actual pointer.  before calling exit, always free any allocated memory

Comment: regarding this line: '  } while (tmplen == CHUNK - 1 && tmpbuf[CHUNK - 2] != '\n');' there is no assurance that tmplen will exactly equal CHUNK-1.  this logic problem needs correction.

Comment: @user3629249: How did you compile it? With `cc -Wall -g det.c -o det` I don't get any warnings.

Comment: @user3629249: If `tmplen` is less than `CHUNK - 1` it means that there was not sufficient data, so the cycle can end.

Comment: the compile statement needs -Wall -Wextra -pedantic, at a minimum, to enable all the warnings, there are another dozen or so possible warning parameters, but those three will reveal about 99 percent of all compiler recognized problems.

Comment: this line: 'size_t length = sizeof(matrix[0]) / sizeof(matrix[0][0]);' will not calculate the number of rows in a matrix.  Either keep track of that info as rows are added and pass an additional parameter to the free_matrix function.  or over allocate the array of pointers and always set unused pointers to NULL so looping through the array, it can stop when an NULL pointer is encountered.

Comment: per the posted code, the user enters a new line after entering each line of the matrix.  so if CHUNK is 100   and user enters 12 36 45<newline>  then the loop would exit without having entered the following rows of the matrix

Comment: @user3629249 So it should be `tmplen <= CHUNK - 1`, right? Now I'm refactoring the code to use a pointer to a struct everywhere, it should be easier to manage. Something like this:

    `struct Matrix {
        size_t size;
        double **rows;
    }`

Comment: function parse_into() has this line: 'first_row = realloc(first_row, 2 * N * sizeof(first_row));'  which has a couple of problems.  1) if realloc fails, then the prior pointer to allocated memory is lost.  2)  there is no check that realloc was successful.  3) The allocation is for 'double' values, not the size of a pointer.  Since double is (typically) 8bytes, this realloc does not change the total size of the original allocation rather than doubling the size of the original allocation, probably not what was intended

Comment: @user3629249 Thanks for all the suggestions! I tried to fix all the issues and I edited the question with a link to the correct working code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many problems with your code.

First, you don't correctly initialize the pointers you pass to `realloc`. You must ensure they are all either valid or NULL. That is not the case here, and in multiple places.

In your `allocate_matrix` function, you will lose pointers when you reallocate to a smaller size.

In your `free_matrix` function, `sizeof(matrix[0])` means `sizeof(double*)` which is constant. It is definitely not what you want. Same for `sizeof(matrix[i])` in `allocate_matrix`.

In your `parse_into`, you overwrite the `matrix` pointer but this change is lost after the call and the matrix will not be freed.

In the same function, you only call `free(row)` once, despite calling `readline` multiple times. `readline` will allocate a new buffer at each call, since `input` is set to NULL in the function.

Again in `parse_into`, you never free `first_row`.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your review. I fixed the last two problems which were oversights. However, I don't know how to solve the first four problems. It seems to me that this version has so many issues that it would be more convenient to rewrite from scratch `allocate_matrix`. What do you suggest?

Comment: @rubik Maybe you should define a struct Matrix, with an `int` for the size and a `double**`. Then pass a Matrix* to all your functions. In short, define  and use Matrix like a C++ class. And enforce proper realloc use in your functions. Properly initialize your pointers to NULL. Don't forget the side effect of reducing an array with realloc (you lose data, free it before).

Answer (score 2):

You do know that you call `allocate_matrix` *twice*? Once in the `main` function, and again in the `parse_into` function. The problem with that is that the allocation done in `parse_into` is only made to the local copy the `matrix` argument, this change will not be passed out to the calling function.

This will of course lead to a memory leak, as well as the data you read will not be in the matrix you allocated from the `main` function.

To solve this you either need to pass `matrix` *by reference* (or at least emulate it) to `parse_into`, or come up with another way of passing this new matrix back to `main`.

Comment: The local copy of `allocate_matrix` is NOT lost, it is returned at the end.

Comment: @ElderBug I'm talking about `parse_into`, the result of the call to `allocate_matrix` inside `parse_into` is lost when the `parse_into` function returns.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. I've acknowledged all the problems my code has, but I can't find a way to solve them. Also, isn't passing a double pointer *already* passing by reference?

Comment: @rubik I suggest you step through the `pasre_into` function line by line in a debugger, then you will most likely see the value of `matrix` change as the result of the call to `allocate_matrix`, but when you leave `parse_into` you should notice that the value of `matrix` in the `main` function is still the *old* value. That's because you don't pass `matrix` by reference, to do that you need a pointer to `matrix` which would be of type `double***`, and you would pass it using the address-of operator `&`, and in the function you need to use the dereference operator `*`.

Answer (score 2):

You allocate memory for `matrix` in `main()`

```
matrix = allocate_matrix(matrix, MATRIX);
N = parse_into(matrix);
```

but then in `parse_into()` you discard that pointer (and its memory) when you do

```
matrix = allocate_matrix(matrix, N);
```

You also have a potential bug. You are allocating memory by passing a `NULL` pointer to `realloc()`. This will work, but when you `free()` the memory, you don't reset the pointer to `NULL`. So if you re-used that pointer, say in another iteration, `realloc()` will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Also, note that:

```
if (!(matrix[i] = realloc(matrix[i], sizeof(matrix[i]) * side)))
```

is wrong. sizeof(matrix[i]) is the size of pointer, but here you want the size of double